# Landau levels versus Bloch states

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators

People talk a lot about quantum Hall effects without Landau levels. It seems that there are two kinds of quantum Hall effects, with Landau levels or without Landau levels. In the second case, it is with Bloch states.

The question is, what is the relation between Landau levels and Bloch states? In [Haldane's 1988 paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.61.2015), he stated that 'In this case, the electron states retain their usual Bloch state character.'

It sounds that a Landau state is quite different from a normal Bloch state. In which sense?

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, Bloch states are just the solutions for electronic wavefunction in periodic potential. Landau levels appear from different problem: free electron in magnetic field. In real situations these two ideas are always in conjunction because we apply magnetic field to crystal. If, for example, periodic potential represents small perturbation to the hamiltonian, then in this case we also should see some traits of Landau levels in the experiment. So this may be the case for 'as free as possible' electrons. Conversely, if the perturbation causing Landau levels to the original Bloch wavefunction is small, than electron will behave mostly as it did in its Bloch state. This should hold for small magnetic fields. I guess that this is reflected in the paper by the smallness of phase $\phi$, which comes from phase (something like fraction of fluxes $\frac{\Phi}{\Phi_0}$), emerging from magnetic field. Because $\phi$ is small, solutions have the character of Bloch states.